# Web Pages acting weirdly in Safari. (All other Browsers tested, the web page acts weirdly only in Safari for macOS)

Tags: macos, mac, safari

I don't know why but for some days Instagram (Web Version) is acting weird when it (webpage) is being loaded in Safari.

When I am clicking on my account page, all the contents within the my account page is getting aligned to the left, this wasn't the case a few days before, everything (All Contents - Posts, profile Pic, etc.) used to be centrally aligned.

This happens only in Safari. I have tried with other web browsers, this weird issue doesn't occurs in other browsers for macOS

This pic depicts my Account page where everything used to be centrally aligned be fore and now it's left aligned

[image]

The Single Post page is also left aligned, which used to be centrally aligned before.

[image]

This is a screenshot from Firefox and everyhting seems to be fine over here. (It's centrally Aligned)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web design can be a tricky business. When you consider all the different browsers that exist multiplied by the the different versions of each browser, you begin to wonder how any web page can be written that works correctly in all cases.

Generally a good web designer uses tools where a page is designed using one version of a browser, then the page is submitted to software that modifies the page to work with each type of browser and each types older versions. When the web page is viewed conditionals can then be evaluated to correct for differences in browser types and versions.

Also, there are services that allow a web designer the opportunity to view a web page using one type of browser, but see how the page would appear using a different type of browser. Thus eliminating the need to have all the different types of browsers and versions, operating systems, computers, tables and phones available to test a web page.

In your case, either a mistake was made while testing this web page or instagram does not full test their web pages. In other words, this web page could be rewritten to use a differ positioning compatible with all browsers or have conditionals that would accommodate Safari.

Comment: This wasn't the case a few days ago. Safari was showing up the page the correct one but don't know what's wrong with Safari for the last few days I tried to clear Safari caches and all but nothing happens and one more thing I hae certain services disabled for Safari like bookmarks sync agent but I don't think it has any connection with this issue.

Comment: You make the assumption the problem is with your Mac and Safari. For all we know,  Instagram make has made changes that is causing this problem.

Comment: I think the problem is it with Instagram then let's see what happens in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

## Reload from Origin

Try asking Safari to reload all the page resources from the origin server. Do this with the hidden menu item:

> In Safari, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and select **View > Reload Page From Origin**

This will ensure that all the files are downloaded from the original web site and not from various caches. Occasionally an out of date cached file can conflict with a partly reloaded page, causing the strange layout you are seeing.

Comment: After I tried this Instagram is not loading anymore the progress bar is stuck and the web page doesn't loads.

Comment: Then there is a problem connecting to the web server. Is your connection filtered, blocked, or managed by an IT department?

Comment: It's a Gigabit home connection and it doesn't has any sort of filters,firewalls or any obstacle blocking and monitoring outgoing connections.